# images aren't loading on localhost of react app but load perfectly on deployed version

Tags: reactjs, localhost

Hello I recently deployed my portfolio but still need to make some changes. The deployed version through github loads fine but the images when I npm start my code on my computer wont show. What is it that im missing?

here is my github for my portfolio: https://github.com/DH0710/dh07-portfolio

Ive tried looking at my images folder making sure all the paths are correct. Moving my images folder from public to src.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.